# Doesn't show the back button in navigation bar in ios 9

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios8, ios9

I have updated ios 9 in my phone. After that I have installed my app in my phone. I have faced the problem for doesn't show the back button in navigation bar. but show the back button in navigation bar in ios 8.

what is the problem for that? How can I resolve that problem?

Comment: Can you click and check where back action works.. Bcoz some time tint color and navigation bar color will same.

Comment: no. I have checked that. That is not a problem. may be some time ios 9 introduce the back button for one app to another app. that may be hide the  back button in navigation bar

Comment: post some code and screenshot.

Comment: I have resolved that issue just now. no need put the navigation controller for each view. put the navigation controller start view only. now working back button very well

Comment: Resolved my issue too...thanks :)